# React functional component not rendering because it doesn't get the parameter on time

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to represent an array in a table using a library. The format of the array is [{"transaction_amount": 39.98, "transaction_date": 2020}, {...}]. Everything works fine when I assign a static value to the constant (for testing purposes) but if I pass a parameter to the functional component, then it doesn't render.. The below code doesn't work:

```
const App = ({transactions, failed}) => {

const columns = [
        { title: "Transaction Amount", data: "transaction_amount" },
        { title: "Transaction Date", data: "transaction_date" },
  ];
console.log(failed)
 if(failed){
    columns.push({ title: "Order ID", data: 'order_id'});
  }else{
    columns.push({ title: "Available Amount (after transaction)", data: 'available_amount'});
  }
console.log(transactions)
if(transactions.length == 0){
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
}else{
  return (
    <>
      <h5 className="mt-2 mb-4 text-center">Recent Transactions</h5>
      <DataTable
        data={transactions}
        columns={columns}
        striped={true}
        hover={true}
        responsive={true}
      />
    </>
  );
}
};
```

I've tried conditionally rendering the component but it doesn't work. The error I'm getting is:

```
var render = function render() {
> 26 |   return currentRows.map(function (row, i) {
     | ^  27 |     return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("tr", {
  28 |       key: i,
  29 |       onClick: function onClick() {
```

Comment: can you include the actual error text? Right now you're just including the location of the error.

Comment: You tagged it with `redux`, so would show where you get the state from the store?

Comment: @Slbox The error is "TypeError: currentRows.map is not a function"

Comment: In this case it means that `currentRows` is not an array. Are you using some library for `<DataTable />` ? If so, the issue might be with that library, although more likely you are passing some invalid prop to the component.

Comment: Yes, DataTable is a library. They had an example which was formatted as an array of arrays but it was an array of objects. I've removed the JSON parsing in my back-end and it now worked.
Thank you for the help